# Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined when calling AJAX

Tags: html, jquery

When running a javascript function that calls for AJAX, i keep getting this same error.
I've encountered this error on other projects and the problem was always that I wasn't calling Jquery beforehand. But I am now, both the online version and the local version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="contagens.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align: center; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">

    <form id="formContagem">

        <label>Nome da Empresa</label>
        <input style="border: 1px solid black;" type="text" name="contagem" id="nome">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Contagem</label>
        <input style="border: 1px solid black;" type="text" name="contagem" id="contagem">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Valor a Pagar</label>
        <input style="border: 1px solid black;" type="text" name="contagem" id="valor">
        <br>
    
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="inserirContagem()">Inserir Contagem</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function inserirContagem(){

    var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
    var contagem = document.getElementById('contagem');
    var valor = document.getElementById('valor');

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        data: {nome: nome, contagem: contagem, valor: valor, op: 1},
        url: "model.php",
        success: function(resultado){

            console.log(resultado);
            document.getElementById('formContagem').reset();

        }
    })
}
```

The function is being called on a button inside the body. Any idea how to fix it? Maybe I'm just missing something minor.

Comment: Why are you including two copies of jQuery? We also need a [mcve] and not just what's in the head

Comment: the whole code is now on the question! I tried using them individually and then together, just in case, none of the options work

Comment: @curious remove one of the jqueries copy. In case this doesn't helps, you can try wrapping your function in a jQuery document ready function to ensure that jQuery is fully loaded before the function is called. $(document).ready(function() {})

Comment: @VivekK. do i place the jquery function on the onClick function? or in the function itself in the js file? i tried removing one of the jqueries copy and it did not work, and wrapping the jquery function in the js file also did not work